# Import data in MongoDB replacing the existing docs

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I am new to MongoDB I am trying to import the JSON file from my local to MongoDB using the command

```
mongoimport --db testingdb --collection dbcollection1 --file books.json --jsonArray
```

It appends the data to the collection perfectly. But when I edit some documents in the same JSON file and redo the command instead of updating the docs it appends the same data again. So how can I added the docs to the collection by updating the docs already present in the db?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`--upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsert) and likely [`--upsertFields`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsertFields) as well. But your question does not state which fields these would be in order to call the document a "match".

Comment: i need a field named as recipe_name to be same  in order to call the document a "match"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the [`--upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsert) and [`--upsertFields`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsertFields) options handle this. The latter is used when a field or fields other than `_id` determine how to match the document.

In your case:

```
mongoimport --db testingdb --collection dbcollection1 \
--upsert --upsertFields recipe_name \
--file books.json --jsonArray
```

And if a match is found for that field in the collection then the data present will be overwritten by the imported data.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to figure out the objects did not match in the json? Here is the error message for the ones it did not match: 'error inserting documents: E11000 duplicate key error collection: info.restaurants index: slug_1 dup key: { : null }'. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!